# Creating a PHP Online Grading System on Linux: exec Behavior, Process IDs, and grep

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, exec, javac

## Background

I am writing a simple online judge (a code grading system) using PHP and MySQL. It takes submitted codes in C++ and Java, compiles them, and tests them.

This is Apache running PHP 5.2 on an old version of Ubuntu.

## What I am currently doing

I have a php program that loops infinitely, calling another php program by

```
//for(infinity)
    exec("php -f grade.php");
//...
```

every tenth of a second. Let's call the first one `looper.php` and the second one `grade.php`. (Checkpoint: `grade.php` should completely finish running before the "for" loop continues, correct?)

`grade.php` pulls the earliest submitted code that needs to be graded from the MySQL database, puts that code in a file (`test.[cpp/java]`), and calls 2 other php programs in succession, named `compile.php` and `test.php`, like so:

```
//...
exec("php -f compile.php");
//...
//for([all tests])
    exec("php -f test.php");
//...
```

(Checkpoint: `compile.php` should completely finish running before the "for" loop calling `test.php` even starts, correct?)

`compile.php` then compiles the program in `test.[cpp/java]` **as a background process**. For now, let's assume that it's compiling a Java program and that `test.java` is located in a subdirectory. I now have

```
//...
//$dir = "./sub/" or some other subdirectory; this may be an absolute path
$start_time = microtime(true); //to get elapsed compilation time later
exec("javac ".$dir."test.java -d ".$dir." 2> ".$dir
        ."compileError.txt 1> ".$dir."compileText.txt & echo $!", $out);
//...
```

in `compile.php`. It's redirecting the output from `javac`, so `javac` should be running as a background process... and it seems like it works. The `$out` should be grabbing the process id of `javac` in `$out[0]`.

## The real problem

I want to stop compiling if for some reason compiling takes more than 10 seconds, and I want to end `compile.php` if the program stops compiling before 10 seconds. Since the `exec("javac...` I called above is a background process (or is it?), I have no way of knowing when it has completed without looking at the process id, which should have been stored in `$out` earlier. Right after, in `compile.php`, I do this with a 10 second loop calling `exec("ps ax | grep [pid].*javac");` and seeing if the pid still exists:

```
//...
$pid = (int)$out[0];
$done_compile = false;

while((microtime(true) - $start_time < 10) && !$done_compile) {

    usleep(20000); // only sleep 0.02 seconds between checks
    unset($grep);
    exec("ps ax | grep ".$pid.".*javac", $grep);

    $found_process = false;

    //loop through the results from grep
    while(!$found_process && list(, $proc) = each($grep)) {
        $boom = explode(" ", $proc);
        $npid = (int)$boom[0];

        if($npid == $pid)
            $found_process = true;
    }
    $done_compile = !$found_process;
}

if(!done_compile)
    exec("kill -9 ".$pid);
//...
```

... which doesn't seem to be working. At least some of the time. Often, what happens is `test.php` starts running before the `javac` even stops, resulting in `test.php` not being able to find the main class when it tries to run the java program. I think that the loop is bypassed for some reason, though this may not be the case. At other times, the entire grading system works as intended.

Meanwhile, `test.php` also uses the same strategy (with the X-second loop and the grep) in running a program in a certain time limit, and it has a similar bug.

I think the bug lies in the `grep` not finding `javac`'s pid even when `javac` is still running, resulting in the 10 second loop breaking early. Can you spot an obvious bug? A more discreet bug? Is there a problem with my usage of `exec`? Is there a problem with `$out`? Or is something entirely different happening?

Thank you for reading my long question. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Since nobody is answering, here is the short version of my question: How do I create a background process with PHP such that 1) I can kill it after X seconds and 2) I can tell if the process has ended on its own before 10 seconds is up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came up with this code that will run a process, and terminate it if it runs longer than `$timeout` seconds.  If it terminates before the timeout, it will have the program output in `$output` and the exit status in `$return_value`.

I have tested it and it seems to work well.  Hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

```
<?php

$command = 'echo Hello; sleep 30'; // the command to execute
$timeout = 5; // terminate process if it goes longer than this time in seconds

$cwd = '/tmp';  // working directory of executing process
$env = null;    // environment variables to set, null to use same as PHP

$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

// start the process
$process    = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
$startTime  = time();
$terminated = false;
$output     = '';

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // process was started
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    // loop infinitely until timeout, or process finishes
    for(;;) {
        usleep(100000); // dont consume too many resources

        $stat = proc_get_status($process); // get info on process

        if ($stat['running']) { // still running
            if (time() - $startTime > $timeout) { // check for timeout
                // close descriptors
                fclose($pipes[1]);
                fclose($pipes[0]);
                proc_terminate($process); // terminate process
                $return_value = proc_close($process); // get return value
                $terminated   = true;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // process finished before timeout
            $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // get output of command
            // close descriptors
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            fclose($pipes[0]);

            proc_close($process); // close process
            $return_value = $stat['exitcode']; // set exit code
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$terminated) {
        echo $output;
    }

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
    if ($terminated) echo "Process was terminated due to long execution\n";
} else {
    echo "Failed to start process!\n";
}
```

References: [proc_open()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), [proc_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php), [proc_get_status()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php), [proc_terminate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am taking a different approach now, but I will base my work off of your solution if my new method does not work. It seems like I won't need a better answer anymore, so I'll check yours.

Comment: Hello, this doesn't seem to work if they submit a solution with an infinite loop :(