# PHP fsocketopen Though Proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am currently using PHP to open up a port 43 connection to get whois information directly from a registry using this code.

```
// connecting to the whois server.  
$handle = fsockopen($server, 43);  
        if (!$handle)  
            return false; // connection failure   


        //asking the server  
        fwrite($handle, $domain_name."\r\n");  


        // getting response  
        $response = '';  
        while (!feof($handle))  
            $response .= fgets($handle, 1024);  

        fclose($handle);
```

It works great however I want to connect though a proxy server so I route my intertent connection through it. If this were able to use cURL I would use curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip_address . ':4040'); but i can not find a way to do this using fsocketopen. How can I accomplish this either with cURL or fsocketopen()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets dont have proxy. Just gateways and routers are in-the-middle (if any). You were talking about cURL, that it has proxy - it only uses http/s proxy service. For example, if you have http proxy service on server example.com:8080 you first need to open connection to server example.com (socket) on port 8080 and then send your request, proxy will forward your request and return response. In your case, you just open tcp connection on port 43 on specific host and exchange data directly with target server. If you dont want to do this directly and reveal your ip (or something) you'll need some service too. If you have access to other machine you could use it to do the job. If you want to do it manually you could use ssh or something like that, if you want to make it automatized, you'll probably need to write service on your middle server because you probably wont find any public proxy servers with other protocols than popular http, ftp, ...

Hope this helps.

By the way I see no reason why you should use proxy on whois service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy to relay the TCP connection from your machine to the SOCKS server to the WHOIS server but you would have to implement the SOCKS communication protocol over `fsockopen`.

Another method would be to use [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) on the server and execute it via PHP.  I've answered a similar question here ( [How to capture and feed telnet using php and shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461929/how-to-capture-and-feed-telnet-using-php-and-shell-scripting/11462845#11462845) ) which shows how to invoke proxychains from PHP to execute a WHOIS command on a remote server and read the response.